# Django. Как проверить с какой страницы, пришёл реквест?

Tags: python, django, view, шаблоны

Есть проблема. Существует форма, добавления товара в корзину, и если товар добавлялся из детального товара, должен быть редирект на корзину, если же товар добавлялся из категорий, редирект должен быть на текущую категорию.
Как устроить проверку url, с которого пришёл реквест?
p.s. Как кастомизировать внешний вид IntegerField формы?

Comment: Во-первых, реферер, однако он доступен не всегда. Во-вторых, вам ничего не должно мешать добавить дополнительные данные в том коде, который выполняет запрос, добавляющий товар в корзину (например, этот самый url)

Comment: Ну передайте в url лишнюю цифру - ноль или один в зависимости от того, из какого шаблона выполняется форма (шаблон детального товара или категорий), и проверяйте - если ноль пришел, то туда-то перенапрвляйте, если один, то туда-то. Способ возможно костыльный, но реализовать это просто (не знаю как по-другому)